# Перемножение матриц

Tags: c#, массивы, матрицы

хотел бы узнать, как можно перемножить две матрицы 3x3 в C#.
Желательно подогнать это под мой код массивов.
(язык C#)

```c
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[,] A = new int[3, 3];
    int[,] B = new int[3, 3];
    int C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            A[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 15);
            Console.Write(A[i, j]+ ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            A[z, x] = rand.Next(1, 15);
            Console.Write(A[z, x] + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread72083.html  - тут исчерпывающий ответ на ваш вопрос. Задавайте вопрос более конкретно, если непонятно

Answer (score 1):

Перед этим заведите матрицу `r` правильной размерности.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < B.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    for (int k = 0; k < B.GetLength(0); k++)
                    {
                        r[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j];
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: А как ее в консоль вывести ? А то у меня если в любой из вложенных циклов писать Console.Write(r[i, j]); то будут нули выводиться

Comment: Также как и вывод любой матрицы циклами - двойным циклом `for`

Comment: Все равно выводит нули, в чем ошибка может быть ?

Comment: Так проблема с перемножением или с выводом?) Проверьте дебагом значения результирующего массива на значения элементов массива)

Comment: @AlCher Мы не знаем, в чем может быть ошибка, так как не видим Вашего кода.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.Sleep(100); нужен для того, чтобы приостановить поток, потому что класс Random генерирует числа на основе текущего времени, если этого не сделать, то числа в двух матрицах будут одинаковыми. Остальное должно быть понятно

```
 private const int DIM = 3;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A = InitializationMatrix();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        var B = InitializationMatrix();            
        var C = MultiplicationMatrix(A, B);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int[,] InitializationMatrix()
    {
        var matrix = new int[DIM, DIM];

        var rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DIM; j++)
            {
                matrix[i, j] = rand.Next(1, 15);
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + ", ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return matrix;
    }
    private static int[,] MultiplicationMatrix(int[,] firstMatrix, int[,] secondMatrix)
    {
        var resultMatrix = new int[DIM, DIM];

        for (int i = 0; i < firstMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < secondMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < secondMatrix.GetLength(0); k++)
                {
                    resultMatrix[i, j] += firstMatrix[i, k] * secondMatrix[k, j];
                }
                Console.Write(resultMatrix[i, j] + ", ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return resultMatrix;
    }
```